# OpenSSL - as alternative to Lua encdec.hmacsha256()

Tags: lua, openssl, hmac

I’m trying to re-platform a Lua script that uses modules I can’t find. The one I’m stuck on is  `encdec.hmacsha256()` which is used in this specific command `sig = encdec.hmacsha256(ciphertext, hmac_key, true)`

I’m looking to use openSSL instead in order to create the signature,  but I’ve been unable to successfully construct the required command line. Please could someone help?

(FYI - I’m a newbie when it comes to encryption and ciphers etc.)

Here is the Lua code where it fits in..

```
local hmac_key = createHMACKey()
print ("Returned hmac_key = " ..hmac_key)
local hmac_key_HEX = binascii.hexlify(hmac_key)
print ("Returned hmac_key_HEX = " ..hmac_key_HEX)
--------------------------------

--orig = local sig = encdec.hmacsha256(ciphertext, hmac_key, true)
local opensslHMAC256command = "openssl sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:" ..ciphertext..hmac_key
local command = assert(io.popen(opensslHMAC256command, 'r'))
local output = command:read('*all')
command:close()

print("opensslHMAC256command in = " ..output)
local file = "etc/encryptedpayload1.txt"
local outf = io.open(file, "w")
outf:write(payload)
outf:close()

local file = "etc/encryptedpayload2.txt"
local outf = io.open(file, "r")
local encreading = outf:read("*all")
print("opensslHMAC256command out = " ..encreading)
outf:close()

local sig = encreading
print("sig = " ..sig)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
local sig = encdec.hmacsha256(ciphertext, hmac_key, true)
```

with

```
local sha = require("sha2")
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext))
```

The library is [here](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/pure_lua_SHA)

Comment: Hi @Egor - when i run your suggested command, i get the following `Runtime error: Line 65: attempt to call field 'hmac' (a nil value)`

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Here you go..   local sha = require("sha2")
local hmac_key_HEX="568D18FBF3B3E4D30D1BCDB85D0D920DE60FE5E5EFA13AC2C9F4E1C567767A16"
local ciphertext="€`c|È¾”Á¡A‡a-TZäBµV M;\ d9ioã!0ØmïÓT1µ‡×ÎJdâI¼"
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext))
print(sig)

Comment: And where is the "Line 65" in your script?

Comment: I gave you a condensed version, so with that one the message is `Runtime error: Line 4: attempt to call field 'hmac' (a nil value)` - which is this line `local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext)) `

Comment: Please show the content of `sha` : `for k in pairs(sha) do print(k) end`

Comment: Hi, sure, the output is `_M     
_NAME     
_PACKAGE `

Comment: Hi @Egor, did that help ?

Comment: Hi @Egor, sorry to chase, any ideas on the error?

Comment: Something is very wrong with installing Lua modules on your system.  Install a test module `test123.lua` with content `return {x=42}` and try to use it: `print(require("test123").x)`, you should see `42` printed.  Do you see `42`?

Comment: Thanks @Egor, - doing it the way you suggested didn’t work, nothing came back. But if I change the contents of the`test123.lua` file so it’s `module("test123", package.seeall) ` and have just ` x = 42` as the content. Using `print(require("test123").x)` will return `42`. FYI - i’m running Lua v5.1 on an home automation (Vera Home Control) controller..

Comment: OK, modify the last line of `sha2.lua` from `return sha` to `x=sha`, add `module("sha2", package.seeall)` and use the module as `local sha = require("sha2").x`  BTW, what is the RAM size available to Lua on your controller hardware?

Comment: Thanks - I made the changes to `sha2.lua`, but `local sha = require("sha2").x` returns the following error ``attempt to index local 'sha' (a nil value) ``. If I remove the `.x` i get the original error again which was `attempt to call field 'hmac' (a nil value)` .  If i do this `local sha = require("sha2")
for k, v in pairs(sha) do print(k,v)end` it returns `_M     table: 0x137a7f0     
_NAME     sha2     
_PACKAGE` . And finally when it comes to RAM on the controller, its `256 MB DDR3`

Comment: Try `local sha = require("sha2")._M` or `local sha = require("sha2")._M.x`

Comment: Not sure what’s going in but all local sha attempts returned `attempt to index local 'sha' (a nil value)` message.  if try them a similar approach via print command, only `print(require("sha2")._M)`  returns something which was `table: 0x14d1680`.

Comment: If I add `z = “Egor"` to sha2.lua file. I can get that returned using `print(require("sha2").z)`

Comment: Then try `local sha = require("sha2").x`

Comment: Sadly it’s still the same error message as when we tried that earlier.  `attempt to index local 'sha' (a nil value) `. Here is the test code I used.. `local sha = require("sha2").x
local hmac_key_HEX="568D18FBF3B3E4D30D1BCDB85D0D920DE60FE5E5EFA13AC2C9F4E1C567767A16" 
local ciphertext="€`c|È¾”Á¡A‡a-TZäBµV M;\ d9ioã!0ØmïÓT1µ‡×ÎJdâI¼" 
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext)) 
print(sig)`

Comment: Reminder - this error `Runtime error: Line 4: attempt to call field 'hmac' (a nil value) ` is returned by the following code `local sha = require("sha2")
local hmac_key_HEX="568D18FBF3B3E4D30D1BCDB85D0D920DE60FE5E5EFA13AC2C9F4E1C567767A16" 
local ciphertext="€c|È¾”Á¡A‡a-TZäBµV M;\ d9ioã!0ØmïÓT1µ‡×ÎJdâI¼" 
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext)) 
print(sig)` so the local `sha` block can be seen?

Comment: Why `z="Egor"` works, but `x=sha` does not work?  It is so similar.

Comment: It does work (partly i think). When using `sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext))` we can get past the ‘sha’ is nil value with `local sha = require("sha2")` but  we’re then hit with ‘hmac’ is a nil value next ?  So something in that sequence of sha calls is not finding hmac,

Comment: Try to replace the last line of the module `x=sha` with `_G.sha=sha`, and replace the line in the main program `local sha = require("sha2")...` with `local sha = _G.sha`.  Does it work?

Comment: Sadly, we’re back to `attempt to index local 'sha' (a nil value)`…. :-( going back to `local sha = require("sha2")` we’re back to ‘hmac’ being nil, however i noticed the following reported in my IDE, if this helps.. `sha={ z="Egor", _M=sha, _NAME="sha2", _PACKAGE="" }`

Comment: The following example works for me in Lua 5.1:  [sha2.lua](https://pastebin.com/0Yy4mtYB), [main.lua](https://pastebin.com/befsrdup).  Does it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake.  A variable named `x` is already defined in the module `sha2.lua`, that's why the code does not work.  You should use `z` instead of `x`.

Comment: Please don’t apologise, I’m very grateful for the help, but I’m afraid we’re not quite there yet. Using`local sha = require("sha2").z` does gets us a little further, but my next error is `Runtime error: Line 4797: attempt to get length of local 'key' (a nil value)` (I’m still using the 5 lines of code I’ve shared above..) - on a positive note, at least we’ve moved forward.. crossing my fingers we’ll get there..

Comment: You initialized `hmac_key_HEX` but passed `hmac_key` (undefined variables are `nil`, getting length of `nil` raised the error)

Comment: Hi, thanks again;  what call should be initialised ?  All I have is the `hmac_key` and the `ciphertext` ? The goal is to find an alternative to another code/module that was used which had`sig = encdec.hmacsha256(ciphertext, hmac_key, true) `. The current test code `local sha = require("sha2").z
local hmac_key_HEX="568D18FBF3B3E4D30D1BCDB85D0D920DE60FE5E5EFA13AC2C9F4E1C567767A16" 
local ciphertext="€c|È¾”Á¡A‡a-TZäBµV M;\ d9ioã!0ØmïÓT1µ‡×ÎJdâI¼" 
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext)) 
print(sig)`

Comment: You can convert `local hmac_key = sha.hex_to_bin(hmac_key_HEX)`

Comment: Thanks ever so much @Egor, it’s seems to be working now, no errors are being thrown. I now need to work it into my code. While I have you, do you know of any pure Lua libraries/modules that can replace this `local aes_cbc, err = aes:new(key, nil, aes.cipher(128, 'cbc'), { iv = iv }, nil, 0) ; local decrypted = aes_cbc:decrypt(encdec.base64dec(data))` (encrypt & decrypt) ?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular situation, we had to alter the require sha2 module and the associated local call, (adding a `.z =` option) so the function could be requested correctly

```
local sha = require("sha2").z
local sig = sha.hex_to_bin(sha.hmac(sha.sha256, hmac_key, ciphertext))
```